# How to set custom action bar in a Fragment?

Tags: android

I'm using BottomNavigationView and with fragments , I want to create custom action bar on that fragment. Please give me some advice.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you want to include Custom action bar on Fragment?

Comment: When I click the items in bottom navigation view tool bar title doesn't change. I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Comment: @ZinZing If this answer has helped you, then please accept it by clicking the ✔ icon on the left, below the score.